# Hadoop and Hbase configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hbase

I am using windows 7 and cygwin. I am successfully configure Hadoop 1.0.3 and Hbase 0.94.16 and also create table and insert data in table.
   Now I want to configure Hadoop and Hbase in eclipse(windows 7) so plz suggest if have any idea. Thankyou .

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get "configure Hadoop and Hbase in eclipse"?DO you mean how to run Hbase and MR programs using eclipse or do you want to run Hadoop and Hbase itself inside Eclipse?

Comment: @Tariq I want to run Hadoop and Hbase itself inside Eclipse.I want to create table, insert data in table using coding in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After expanding a whole day finally I got the solution.These are some steps to configure Hbase in Eclipse IDE.

1. Using cygwin all hbase running successfully.
2. Firstly get the some jar file from hbase and hadoop lib folder(hadoop,hbase,hbase-      test,common-logging,commons-configuration)
3. Create a simple java project and configure these all jar files(projectname -> BuildPath ->    configureBuildPath)
4. After these steps attach Hbase config folder in your project(ProjectName -> BuildPath -> Link Source)
5. Than run your program for create table in Hbase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this [tool](https://github.com/bizosys/hsearch-hbase) useful. It comes in pretty handy and allows us to run Hbase inside of Eclipse without much fuss. You just have to pull it into Eclipse and run. Once you run it you'll get a tray icon on your PC. Then you just have to do a right click+start server and it'll start Hbase inside your Eclipse. And the good thing is that you don't need Hadoop setup for this. All the tables, including -ROOT- and .META., will be created on your local FS.

HTH

Comment: thanks @tariq but I have done in eclipse IDE .I will try may be your suggestion more helpful for me. ThankYou again for answer.